# Job Schedule view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to create a view for a report so that I can easily keep track of all of the backups that I have scheduled on a server.  All of these backups are scheduled in subplans of a maintenance plan, so the job names all start with "Backup.".

The problem that I've run into is that I want to easily be able to see when the job is scheduled to run again and how often it's scheduled.  The sysschedules table has the fields freq_type and freq_interval.  The definition of their values can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).  As you can see these fields are, for lack of a better way to describe, accumulative.  I have no idea on how to, in a set-based solution, set it up so that I can see the names of the day.

What'd I'd like to be able to see is something like "Executes every 3 days" or "Executes every monday, tuesday, friday".

How can I write this so that I'm not using layers of case statements to get what I want?

Here's my code so far:

```
select 
    j.job_id,
    j.name,
    s.next_run_date,
    s.next_run_time,
    ss.*
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
    left outer join msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules s
        on j.job_id=s.job_id
    left outer join msdb.dbo.sysschedules ss
        on s.schedule_id=ss.schedule_id
where j.name like 'backup.%'
```

Comment: see if [this script helps](https://bitbucket.org/kshah29/sqlserverscripts/raw/faac44123d334d77d10173cb1da57d6e09b966ff/SQL%20AGENT%20JOB%20related/SQLAgent_JobSchedule_Decoder.txt)

Comment: @Kin the link prompts for login info. Expected?

Comment: Not sure .. its by private repro on bitbucket .. try this https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/20d2815a5dfc52e483bf

Comment: Not sure on your use case, but this free tool might solve your problems: https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/sqljobmanager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is really no other way than to use a case statement if you want the plain English version of all the integer values used by SQL Server (at least to my limited knowledge of T-SQL). This is a common thing needed by a lot of DBAs and there are plenty of scripts out there on the subject. I found the script below from Michelle Ufford to be quite useful in getting a good view of the schedule of jobs running. Since maintenance plans end up as SQL Agent jobs this will show you that as well.

The output you get from the script will give you the frequency, subFrequency, scheduled time and next run time and date. I just took her script and put it as a stored procedure on my server so I can easily run it when needed. You could also put it as a view if you wanted too. Since other folks can come behind me and add jobs and such I like to check it every-now-and-then to see what is going on.

```
/* 
Description: SQL Agent Information
Source: SQLFool, http://sqlfool.com/2012/09/sql-agent-job-script-2/
*/
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @jobHistory TABLE (
    job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,success INT
    ,cancel INT
    ,fail INT
    ,retry INT
    ,last_run_status CHAR(12)
    ,last_execution_id INT
    ,last_duration CHAR(8)
    ,last_execution_start DATETIME
    );

WITH lastExecution
AS (
    SELECT job_id
        ,MAX(instance_id) AS last_instance_id
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    WHERE step_id = 0
    GROUP BY job_id
    )
INSERT INTO @jobHistory
SELECT sjh.job_id
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN sjh.run_status = 1
                AND step_id = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS success
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN sjh.run_status = 3
                AND step_id = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS cancel
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN sjh.run_status = 0
                AND step_id = 0
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS fail
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN sjh.run_status = 2
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS retry
    ,CASE sjh.run_status
        WHEN 0
            THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3
            THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN 4
            THEN 'In Progress'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS last_run_status
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN sjh.step_id = 0
                THEN instance_id
            ELSE NULL
            END) last_execution_id
    ,SUBSTRING(CAST(MAX(CASE 
                    WHEN le.job_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN sjh.run_duration
                    ELSE NULL
                    END) + 1000000 AS VARCHAR(7)), 2, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(MAX(CASE 
                    WHEN le.job_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN sjh.run_duration
                    ELSE NULL
                    END) + 1000000 AS VARCHAR(7)), 4, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(MAX(CASE 
                    WHEN le.job_id IS NOT NULL
                        THEN sjh.run_duration
                    ELSE NULL
                    END) + 1000000 AS VARCHAR(7)), 6, 2) AS last_duration
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN le.last_instance_id IS NOT NULL
                THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(run_date)) + ((run_time / 10000 * 31200) + ((run_time % 10000) / 100 * 60) + (run_time % 10000) % 100) / (86399.9964)
            ELSE '1900-01-01'
            END) AS last_execution_start
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS sjh
LEFT JOIN lastExecution AS le ON sjh.job_id = le.job_id
    AND sjh.instance_id = le.last_instance_id
GROUP BY sjh.job_id
    ,sjh.run_status;

/* We need to parse the schedule into something we can understand */
DECLARE @weekDay TABLE (
    mask INT
    ,maskValue VARCHAR(32)
    );

INSERT INTO @weekDay
SELECT 1
    ,'Sunday'

UNION ALL

SELECT 2
    ,'Monday'

UNION ALL

SELECT 4
    ,'Tuesday'

UNION ALL

SELECT 8
    ,'Wednesday'

UNION ALL

SELECT 16
    ,'Thursday'

UNION ALL

SELECT 32
    ,'Friday'

UNION ALL

SELECT 64
    ,'Saturday';

/* Now let's get our schedule information */
WITH myCTE
AS (
    SELECT sched.name AS 'scheduleName'
        ,sched.schedule_id
        ,jobsched.job_id
        ,CASE 
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 1
                THEN 'Once'
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 4
                AND sched.freq_interval = 1
                THEN 'Daily'
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 4
                THEN 'Every ' + CAST(sched.freq_interval AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' days'
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 8
                THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((
                                    SELECT maskValue
                                    FROM @weekDay AS x
                                    WHERE sched.freq_interval & x.mask <> 0
                                    ORDER BY mask
                                    FOR XML RAW
                                    ), '"/><row maskValue="', ', '), '<row maskValue="', ''), '"/>', '') + CASE 
                        WHEN sched.freq_recurrence_factor <> 0
                            AND sched.freq_recurrence_factor = 1
                            THEN '; weekly'
                        WHEN sched.freq_recurrence_factor <> 0
                            THEN '; every ' + CAST(sched.freq_recurrence_factor AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' weeks'
                        END
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 16
                THEN 'On day ' + CAST(sched.freq_interval AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' of every ' + CAST(sched.freq_recurrence_factor AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' months'
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 32
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 1
                            THEN 'First'
                        WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 2
                            THEN 'Second'
                        WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 4
                            THEN 'Third'
                        WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 8
                            THEN 'Fourth'
                        WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 16
                            THEN 'Last'
                        END + CASE 
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 1
                            THEN ' Sunday'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 2
                            THEN ' Monday'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 3
                            THEN ' Tuesday'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 4
                            THEN ' Wednesday'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 5
                            THEN ' Thursday'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 6
                            THEN ' Friday'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 7
                            THEN ' Saturday'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 8
                            THEN ' Day'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 9
                            THEN ' Weekday'
                        WHEN sched.freq_interval = 10
                            THEN ' Weekend'
                        END + CASE 
                        WHEN sched.freq_recurrence_factor <> 0
                            AND sched.freq_recurrence_factor = 1
                            THEN '; monthly'
                        WHEN sched.freq_recurrence_factor <> 0
                            THEN '; every ' + CAST(sched.freq_recurrence_factor AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' months'
                        END
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 64
                THEN 'StartUp'
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 128
                THEN 'Idle'
            END AS 'frequency'
        ,ISNULL('Every ' + CAST(sched.freq_subday_interval AS VARCHAR(10)) + CASE 
                WHEN sched.freq_subday_type = 2
                    THEN ' seconds'
                WHEN sched.freq_subday_type = 4
                    THEN ' minutes'
                WHEN sched.freq_subday_type = 8
                    THEN ' hours'
                END, 'Once') AS 'subFrequency'
        ,REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(sched.active_start_time)) + CAST(sched.active_start_time AS VARCHAR(6)) AS 'startTime'
        ,REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(sched.active_end_time)) + CAST(sched.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)) AS 'endTime'
        ,REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(jobsched.next_run_time)) + CAST(jobsched.next_run_time AS VARCHAR(6)) AS 'nextRunTime'
        ,CAST(jobsched.next_run_date AS CHAR(8)) AS 'nextRunDate'
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysschedules AS sched
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules AS jobsched ON sched.schedule_id = jobsched.schedule_id
    WHERE sched.enabled = 1
    )
/* Finally, let's look at our actual jobs and tie it all together */
SELECT job.name AS [jobName]
    ,l.name AS [jobOwner]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN job.enabled = 1
            THEN 'Enabled'
        ELSE 'Disabled'
        END AS [jobStatus]
    ,COALESCE(sched.scheduleName, '(unscheduled)') AS [scheduleName]
    ,COALESCE(sched.frequency, '') AS [frequency]
    ,COALESCE(sched.subFrequency, '') AS [subFrequency]
    ,COALESCE(SUBSTRING(sched.startTime, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(sched.startTime, 3, 2) + ' - ' + SUBSTRING(sched.endTime, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(sched.endTime, 3, 2), '') AS [scheduleTime] -- HH:MM
    ,COALESCE(SUBSTRING(sched.nextRunDate, 1, 4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(sched.nextRunDate, 5, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(sched.nextRunDate, 7, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(sched.nextRunTime, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(sched.nextRunTime, 3, 2), '') AS [nextRunDate]
    /* Note: the sysjobschedules table refreshes every 20 min, so nextRunDate may be out of date */
    ,COALESCE(jh.success, 0) AS [success]
    ,COALESCE(jh.cancel, 0) AS [cancel]
    ,COALESCE(jh.fail, 0) AS [fail]
    ,COALESCE(jh.retry, 0) AS [retry]
    ,jh.last_run_status AS [lastRunStatus]
    ,CASE job.notify_level_email
        WHEN 0
            THEN 'None'
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'Succeeds'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'Fails'
        WHEN 3
            THEN 'Completion'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS [EmailNotification]
    ,CASE job.notify_level_eventlog
        WHEN 0
            THEN 'None'
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'Succeeds'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'Fails'
        WHEN 3
            THEN 'Completion'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS [EventLogNotification]
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS job
INNER JOIN master.sys.syslogins l ON l.sid = job.owner_sid
LEFT JOIN myCTE AS sched ON job.job_id = sched.job_id
LEFT JOIN @jobHistory AS jh ON job.job_id = jh.job_id
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysoperators oper ON job.notify_email_operator_id = oper.id
WHERE job.enabled = 1 -- do not display disabled jobs
    AND jh.last_execution_start > '1900-01-01'
ORDER BY jobName
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
GO
```

Comment: Seems like the link to the script, http://sqlfool.com/2009/02/view-sql-agent-jobs-tsql/, is now broken.

Comment: Yep, she took it off the interweb some years back. That whole site is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script will list jobs on a local or remote SQL Server, along with a human readable interpretation of their schedule. It uses internal SSMS code to format the schedule, so you must have it installed on the machine you run the script on.

```
#requires -modules sqlps
#requires -version 3

param([string]$ServerToQuery = ([Environment]::MachineName), [PSCredential]$SqlCredential)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$ssmsAssembly = ls -r 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server' -fi sqlmgmt.dll | sort FullName -Descending | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
Add-Type -Path $ssmsAssembly

$server = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' $ServerToQuery
if($SqlCredential) {
    $server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false
    $server.ConnectionContext.Login = $SqlCredential.UserName
    $server.ConnectionContext.SecurePassword = $SqlCredential.Password
}

$server.JobServer.Jobs | % {
    $job = $_
    $schedules = $_.JobSchedules
    $jobSchedules = $schedules | % {
        $schedule = $_
        $jobScheduleData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.JobScheduleData -ArgumentList $_
        $jobScheduleData.Description
    }

    New-Object psobject -Property ([ordered]@{ Name = $job.Name; Schedules = $jobSchedules -join ', ' })
}
```

Sample output:

```
Name                                 Schedules
----                                 ---------
ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions   Occurs every day every 1 minute(s) between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59. Schedule will be used starting on 16/10/2000.
syspolicy_purge_history              Occurs every day at 02:00:00. Schedule will be used starting on 1/01/2008.
```

Suggested usage:

```
.\GetSchedules.ps1 | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [SQL Agent Job Schedules Script by Jason Brimhall](http://jasonbrimhall.info/2016/03/29/sql-agent-job-schedules/) very useful.

Pros:

1. Runs in SSMS, so no dependencies on PowerShell modules or when you cannot access the servers from PowerShell.
2. Returns the schedule in human readable text